# How to fix this regex so it replaces * properly (between words)?

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

I'm practicing regex. I thought of creating regex that turn `*` into `<em>`, just like with Markdown:

```
el = el.replace(/\*\b/g, '<em>')
el = el.replace(/\b\*|(\.|\,|\?|\!|\*|---|\.\.\.\s)\*/g, '$1</em>')
```

This works in most cases. However, things gets messy if you apply that regex to this:

```
Chicken teriy*ai*ki, r*ai*men noodles, spaghetti a la moneg*ai*sque.
```

It produces this:

```
Chicken teriy<em>ai<em>ki, r<em>ai<em>men noodles, spaghetti a la moneg<em>ai<em>sque. And wait for me, often falling asleep.</em></em></em></em></em></em>
```

How to modify this regex so it produces something like this:

```
 Chicken teriy<em>ai</em>ki, r<em>ai</em>men noodles, spaghetti a la moneg<em>ai</em>sque. And wait for me, often falling asleep.
```

Comment: [`str.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, '<em>$1</em>');`](https://jsfiddle.net/sujybe5w/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge the two branches in your second regex since both end with `\*` pattern, like `(\b|\.|,|\?|!|\*|---|\.{3}\s)\*` (you may even merge the `\.|,|\?|!|\*` single char alternatives into `[.,?!*]`), and then use

```js
var s = "Chicken teriy*ai*ki, r*ai*men noodles, spaghetti a la moneg*ai*sque.";
console.log(
  s.replace(/\*\b([^]*?)(\b|[.,?!*]|---|\.{3}\s)\*/g, '<em>$1$2</em>') 
)
```

**Details**

- `\*\b` - a `*` that is followed with a word char (letter, digit or `_`)
- `([^]*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars, as few as possible (may be replaced with a `[\s\S]` / `[\d\D]` / `[\w\W]` if you need more portability), up to the leftmost occurrence of
- `(\b|[.,?!*]|---|\.{3}\s)` - word boundary,  `.`, `,`, `?`, `!`, `*`, `---`, `...` + whitespace
- `\*` - a `*` char.

Comment: @alexchenco Yes, `/\*\b([^]*?)(\b|[.,?!*]|---|\.{3}\s)\*/g`

Comment: Thanks. This regex is almost perfect. It doesn't work here: `^*Have I seen^ you before?*`.

Comment: @alexchenco Why "doesn't"? It turns into `^<em>Have I seen^ you before?</em>`

Comment: This is the result: `<b class="smallcap"><em>Have I seen</em></b> you before?`

Comment: @alexchenco  No way, you are using some other code.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex `\*([\w ^?.]*?)\*`

Replace with `<em>$1<\em>`

`el = el.replace(/\*([\w ^?.]*?)\*/g, '<em>$1<\em>')`

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/XCjfaO/8)

Comment: This regex is good, but it doesn't work in cases like this: `^*Have I seen^ you before?*`

Answer (score 1):

This should work, it will wrap the characters between * signs into em tags, NOTE: this applies globally on the string provided.

```
 const str = "something that has words surrounded with * signs"
 str.replace(/\*(\w+)\*/g, "<em>$1</em>")
```

Comment: I think this doesn't include `.`