# RegEx- Replacing Alternate Special Character with Open and Close tag

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a sample string where I would like to replace the first star with an opening `<b>` tag and the second star with the closing `</b>` tag  using regular expressions in JavaScript:

Basically I want the following result

```
*Please click CreateActivate email below.* *Please click username passwords below.* *Please click Bill Details below.*
```

this should become like this :

```
<b>Please click CreateActivate email below.</b> <b>Please click username passwords below.</b> <b>Please click Bill Details below.</b>`
```

I have zero knowledge of RegEx hence i have not tried my own, but googling for a solution.

Comment: Have you tried to solve this? If yes, add your attempts in the question.

Comment: You have marked this as a duplicate, can you redirect me towards an answer that is similar to my question, in the meanwhile i will try out the solutions offered by the good Samaritans !

Comment: You can try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52621472/2025923) or my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52621034/how-to-fix-this-regex-so-it-replaces-properly-between-words#comment92175910_52621034).

Comment: In case you are using Java: For cleaning up messy HTML, there is a nice tool https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex in `.replace()` to do this work. In pattern `([^*]+)` match any character except `*` and you can get matched part using `$1` in replacement.

```js
var str = "*Please click CreateActivate email below.* *Please click username passwords below.* *Please click Bill Details below.*";
var newStr = str.replace(/\*([^*]+)\*/g, "<b>$1</b>");
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: can you kindly tell me what is this '$1' ? I see it everywhere.
I will mark you answer as right since it works like a charm , Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Nazir In replacement parameter, `$` refer to regex match group. So in this case `$1` is part matched by `([^*]+)`

Comment: oh , Alright ! cool.